# Making sure websocket connection is using SSL

Tags: node.js, security, nginx, ssl, websocket

here is my nginx config

```
server {
    # listen to all HTTP traffic and redirect to HTTPS
    listen 80;
    server_name hexcards.io www.hexcards.io;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    # listen to all HTTPS traffic
    listen 443 ssl;

    # set root directory and server name
    root /var/www/html;
    server_name hexcards.io www.hexcards.io;

    # all of our SSL certificate info
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/hexcards.io/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/hexcards.io/privkey.pem;

    location /server/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

And here is my nodeJS app

```
import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';
const wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function message(data) {
    console.log('received: %s', data);
  });

  ws.send('something');
});
```

And my client code

```
<script>
const socket = new WebSocket('wss://hexcards.io/server/');
socket.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
  socket.send('Hello Server!');
});
socket.addEventListener('message', function(e){
  console.log('Message from server', e.data);
});
</script>
```

Everything works but I'm just wondering if this is good way to do things or not.  I'm making an online card game and want to serve static content through nginx and also connect to a server via websockets for multiplayer.

Since I am using SSL with nginx I do not need to proxy_pass to https://127.0.0.1:8080 ?  The websocket connection is also encrypted?

Comment: Yes, you are doing everything right, your WevSocket connection is encrypted.

Comment: Thanks for reply Ivan.  So I don't have to worry about hackers seeing sensitive info like passwords with this connection then?  I was thinking about sending username and password with each message to make sure client is who they say they are on the server.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what are the best practices here, however I think it would be only an extra overhead, authorization should occur only when a WebSocket connection is established (I think so, don't know for sure). The only thing I'm sure is that your WS connection is encrypted using the config you've shown in your question.